# Schema validation of multi reference chainied schema

Tags: json, hive, avro, apache-nifi, json-schema-validator

I want to do three things

1. Validate JSON against a JSON-Schema
2. Create JSON-Schema to AVRO Schema converter
3. Create JSON-Schema to Hive Table converter

The problem I'm facing is the Schema has a referencing chain.
I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) JSON Schema Validator which resolves reference and validates but getting some errors at the moment.
But I haven't been able to find any library for the 2nd and the 3rd task.

And I have to create **Nifi processors** for these. I have done it for the first one.

One idea I have is to use an **Inline Parser** to deference the Schemas and create one big schema and use that for the tasks and hopefully, everything will work smoothly afterward.

Any suggestions on what is a good approach to tackle these issues.
One of the schemas is attached. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
  "id": "/schemas/bi/events/identification/carrier",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Users Carrier Identified",
  "description": "A successfully identified carrier of a user",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "carrier_identification_result": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "mno": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Mobile network operator",
          "description": "The Mobile network operator",
          "example": "Telekom"
        },
        "mvno": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": " Mobile virtual network operator",
          "description": "The Mobile virtual network operator.",
          "example": "Mobilcom-Debitel"
        },
        "mcc": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Mobile Country Code",
          "description": "The Mobile Country Code as defined in the ITU-T Recommendation E.212",
          "example": "262"
        },
        "mnc": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Mobile Network Code",
          "description": "The Mobile Network Code as defined in the ITU-T Recommendation E.212",
          "example": "01"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The code ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 for the country",
          "example": "DE"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "mno",
        "country"
      ]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "../identification_service.json"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "constant": "identification.carrier",
          "example": "identification.carrier"
        },
        "event_data": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "../identification_service.json#/definitions/event_data"
            },
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "result": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/carrier_identification_result"
                },
                "required": [
                  "result"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```